# How to stop do while loop after 6 array inputs?

Tags: java

public class AppointmentSchedule {

```
private static final int NUM_APPOINTMENTS = 6;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] scheduled = new String[NUM_APPOINTMENTS];
    Scanner consoleScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    String name;

    for (int z = 0; z < NUM_APPOINTMENTS; z++) {
        scheduled[z] = "";
    }
    System.out.println("To schedule an appointment, Please enter a time between 1PM to 6PM");
    do {
        i = consoleScanner.nextInt();
        try {
            if (i >= 1 && i <= 6) {
                try {
                    if (scheduled[i] == "") {
                        System.out.println("Please enter your name.");
                        name = consoleScanner.next();
                        scheduled[i] = name;
                        System.out.println("Thank you " + name
                                + ", you have been scheduled for " + i
                                + " PM.\n");
                        System.out
                                .println("To schedule an appointment, Please enter a time between 1PM to 6PM");
                    } else {
                        throw new TimeInUseException();
                    }
                } catch (TimeInUseException ex1) {
                    System.out.println(ex1.getMessage());
                }
            } else
                throw new InvalidTimeException();

        } catch (InvalidTimeException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    } while ();
    consoleScanner.close();
}
```

}

What are some techniques to end the do while loop after scheduled[i] is filled up with 6 elements?

Would it look like: while (scheduled[z] != 6)?

Comment: `scheduled[i]` should be `scheduled[i - 1]`

Comment: The first index of an array is 0 not 1, so when you say <= 6 you'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: "_Would it look like: while (scheduled[z] != 6)_" -- No. That won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

Do this `while(i<=5);` this will let your loop run even when `i=6` here `i` is the variable you keep incrementing

Answer (score 2):

Just keep track of how many inputs the user has made. This can be done by declaring

```
int count = 0;
```

before the `do...while` loop and incrementing it from the body of the inner `if`:

```
if (scheduled[i - 1] == "") {
    System.out.println("Please enter your name.");
    name = consoleScanner.next();
    scheduled[i - 1] = name;
    System.out.println("Thank you " + name
                        + ", you have been scheduled for " + i
                        + " PM.\n");
    count++; /* Note this */
    System.out.println("To schedule an appointment, Please enter a time between 1PM to 6PM");
}
```

and finally, change the condition to

```
} while (count < 6);
```